# Split child divs into columns using flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve the column layout shown in the picture below. I need

- Max. 3 columns
- Max. 11 children in a column, then for the 12th child to start a new column
- A light background on every odd-number row, and a dark background on every even-number row

[image]

If there are not enough children to make up a new column, the other columns should *not* fill up the horizontal space, like this:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/qLx7sun1/

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /*flex-direction: column;
  height: calc(20px * 11);*/
}
.parent div {
  flex: 1 0 31%;
  max-width: 31%;
  background: grey;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

This is what I have so far; however the children fill up the parent as rows instead of columns. If I uncomment the `flex-direction: column;` lines it looks really weird. I also haven't managed to get the alternating row backgrounds.

Can I achieve this through CSS/flexbox or do I have to use Javascript?

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/qLx7sun1/1/

Comment: you can also use css columns https://jsfiddle.net/qLx7sun1/2/ dunno if that's what you're going for. if so lemme know and i'll submit as an answer

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thanks, that is closer to what I am trying to achieve, however I need the columns to fill up with 11 items before starting a new column. I have edited my question with an image example of what it should look like with 12 items. :) Also flexbox is preferable, but not a must

Comment: cool, how's this? https://jsfiddle.net/qLx7sun1/5/

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thanks! That is almost what I need. Is it possible to get the 2nd column to stay in the same position whether or not the 3rd column exists? https://jsfiddle.net/qLx7sun1/6/ Here the 2nd column moves to fill up the space to the right.

Comment: Yup, with `align-content` - submitted an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you want to use `flex-direction: column` to get the children in a column, then define `height` to be the height of 11 children, which is their height * 11 + their bottom margin. And add `align-content: flex-start` to keep the columns aligned to the left, instead of creating additional space between the columns.

Then set the `width` of the children instead of using `flex-basis` since it's a column, define a `margin-right` to create space between the columns, and use `:nth-child(even)` or `(odd)` to do the striping.

```css
.parent {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: calc(20px * 11 + 11rem);
  align-content: flex-start;
}
.parent div {
  width: 31%;
  background: grey;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.parent div:nth-child(even) {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
</div>
```